# Django - Fetch values from children via Foreign Key, while looping the parent objects in template

Tags: django, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am quite new to Django and probably this will be totaly noobish question, but I am stuck in this situation and bit help would be much appreciated. I have the following models:

```
class BillType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    bill_type = models.ForeignKey(BillType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    recurring = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.month
```

and the following view:

```
def billingOverview(request):
    bill_types = BillType.objects.all()

    context = {
        'bill_types': bill_types,
    }

    return render(request, 'management/billing-overview.html', context)
```

In the template, I am using the For loop to loop through the BillType objects and that part is working fine. However, for each of the looped BillType objects that are rendered separately in the template, I need to access and show the data for 'month' corresponding to that particular BillType object. Can you help me with an example of how I can do that action?

Thanks,
Bojan

In case the template is needed:

```
                    {% for bill_type in bill_types %}
                    <!-- Billing overview column -->
                    <div>
                        <!-- Billing overview widget -->
                        <div class="bo-widget">
                            <div class="bo-widget-header">
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{{ bill_type.name }}</h2>
                                    <span>Overview of {{ bill_type.name|lower }} bills</span>
                                </div>
                                <a class="bo-addnew-bill" href="{% url 'newBill' bill_type.id %}">+</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bo-widget-content">
                                <span>OVERDUE</span>
                                <div class="bo-widget-bill-cont overdue">
                                    <span class="bo-overdue-warning"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
                                    <div class="bo-bill-info">
                                        <span>January 2020</span>
                                        <div>
                                            <span>2,200 MKD</span>
                                            <p>Due Date: 15 February 2020</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bo-bill-actions">
                                        <a class="bo-bill-paid-action" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <span>LATEST BILL</span>
                                <!-- Latest Bill -->
                                <div class="bo-widget-bill-cont">
                                    <div class="bo-bill-info">
                                        <span>{{ MONTH SHOULD GO HERE }}</span>
                                        <div>
                                            <span>2,200 MKD</span>
                                            <p>Due Date: 15 February 2020</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bo-bill-actions">
                                        <a class="bo-bill-paid-action" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bo-see-all">
                                <a href="javascript:;">See all bills</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I knew that it would take only two rows of code to fix this, but nevermind. I found the solution and here it is in case somebody needs this:

In the Bill model, I've added related_name 'billtype' to the ForeignKey field, so the entire line now will be:

```
bill_type = models.ForeignKey(BillType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='billtype')
```

Now for the queries in the view, I've added the following line

```
bill_types = BillType.objects.all()
```

in order to fetch all of the bill type objects in BillType model; Next, I've added the following line

```
bills = Bill.objects.select_related('bill_type').all()
```

in order to fetch all of the objects in the Bill model, of the related field 'bill_type'.

In the template,

```
{% for bt in bill_types %}
<!-- Billing overview column -->
<div>
    <!-- Billing overview widget -->
    <div class="bo-widget">
        <div class="bo-widget-header">
            <div>
                <h2>{{ bt.name }}</h2>
                <span>Overview of {{ bt.name|lower }} bills</span>
            </div>
            <a class="bo-addnew-bill" href="{% url 'newBill' bt.id %}">+</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bo-widget-content">
            <span>OVERDUE</span>
            <div class="bo-widget-bill-cont overdue">
                <span class="bo-overdue-warning"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
                <div class="bo-bill-info">
                    <span>January 2020</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>2,200 MKD</span>
                        <p>Due Date: 15 February 2020</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bo-bill-actions">
                    <a class="bo-bill-paid-action" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span>LATEST BILL</span>

            <!-- Latest Bill -->
            <div class="bo-widget-bill-cont">
                <div class="bo-bill-info">
                    <span>{{ bt.billtype.last }}</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>{{ bills.amount }} {{ bills.currency}}</span>
                        <p>{{ bills.due_date }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bo-bill-actions">
                    <a class="bo-bill-paid-action" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="bo-see-all">
            <a href="javascript:;">See all bills</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am using For loop to loop through all of the BillType objects and getting the wanted data by using `{{ bt.billtype.last }}`, in order to get corresponding last object from the model's related field.